# Creating an outline of a CGPathRef

Tags: ios, geometry, core-graphics, boolean-logic, cgpath

I have a CGPath created from n overlapping rectangles.  Is there an API to get a new path that is the outline of the original?  Or is it possible to do something clever by filling the original path or creating a clipping path?

Failing any of that, can you recommend a solid reference (online or book) for the maths behind boolean path operations?

**EDIT: Illustrations added for clarity**

For example, 4 overlapping rectangles:

[image]

I want to create a shape that is the outline:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an illustration ? I don't see how the overlapping rectangles and the outline are related.

Comment: @Antoine, have added some illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

If using [Boost.org libraries](http://www.boost.org/) is acceptable to you, there is a [union](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/union_.html) function in [Boost.geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/introduction.html) that does it. [image]